# kaazing... did anyone try it with Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight-3.0

I wonder if anyone tried using Kaazing for client push with Silverlight? How did it go?

http://www.kaazing.org/confluence/display/KAAZING/What+is+Kaazing+Open+Gateway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Speaking as a representative of [Kaazing](http://www.kaazing.com):

[Eikos Partners](http://eikospartners.com) won an innovation award for their application, EPOC, which is an equity trading system running with Silverlight and Kaazing. They have screenshots of their application on their site.

Note that you need the commercial version of Kaazing Gateway to get access to Silverlight support. You can [download it from here](http://www.kaazing.com/download) after you click on "Accept License Agreement."

You can also [read up on Kaazing Gateway and Websockets here](http://tech.kaazing.com).